# If checkbox is checked condition Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple `checkbox` and am trying to determine if it is checked or not in JS.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox == 'true'){
    console.log('test');
}
```

My first `console.log()` returns `true` or `false` as expected, however even if it never goes into the `if()` statement even when it is `true`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was going on but when I had `if(checkbox == true)` I was getting the message saying `true is not defined` as if it was looking for a variable called `true`.

I changed it to using Jquery like so `if($("#checkbox").is(':checked'))`

Comment: you have caused a lot of commotion for something so simple... have a good day my dude. happy coding <3

Comment: Please see my answer. You don't need to be testing for checked checkboxes in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

To check if a checkbox is checked, you don't test it against `"true"` (String). Instead, you examine its `checked` property to see if that is `true` (Boolean). This becomes even easier to deal with because an `if` condition always tests for "truthy" values in the first place, so you don't really need to add that you are testing for `true`.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
// Interpreted as "Is it true that checkbox.checked == true"?
if(checkbox.checked){
    console.log('test');
}

var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
// Interpreted as "Is checkbox.checked.checked true?", which is 
// an error because the checkbox.checked property doesn't have
// a checked property and so checkbox.checked.checked will return
// undefined, which will be false when converted to a Boolean
if(checkbox.checked){
    console.log('test');
}
```

---

But, there is no need to check if a checkbox is checked. Just query the document for only checked checkboxes and whatever is returned is what you work with.

**[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** and **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** allow you to pass any valid CSS selector to them. `.querySelector()` will return the first element that matches the selector and `.querySelectorAll()` will return a node list (HTML Collection) of all matching elements.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Query for only the checked checkboxes and put the result in an array
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  console.clear();
  // Loop over the array and inspect contents
  checked.forEach(function(cb){
    console.log(cb.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="one"> One 
<input type="checkbox" value="two"> Two 
<input type="checkbox" value="three"> Three 
<input type="checkbox" value="four"> Four

<button>Get Checked Checkboxes</button>
```

Comment: but does this answer his question? it's just saying "no no im changing all your code for my professional standpoint!" lol. in your defence it is a bad question...

Comment: upvoted but this will probs be locked anyway i'd say. good stuff

Answer (score 4):

Let's see your code:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox == 'true'){
    console.log('test');
}
```

#### You are giving the checkbox name to a variable holding a boolean value

Change to

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
```

#### You are comparing boolean to string

```
true == 'true'
```

is always `false`. Change to

```
if (checkbox.checked) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

#### You are using the id of checkbox

You probably have several checkboxes with the same `id`. If that is the case, change it to be a `class` and use

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

instead. You will get an array and you will have to iterate it with a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a boolean to a string. What you want is to compare bool to bool as you want.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox == true){
    console.log('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition must be equal to `true` without the quotes, otherwise its comparing to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if boolean variable is equial to string "true"
Just check

```
if(checkbox) {...}
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus `.getElementById()` will return node, `.getElementById().checked` will return boolean, look closer in OP's code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from around true.

```
if(checkbox === true){
    console.log('test');
}
```

Better yet (more concise):

```
if(checkbox){
    console.log('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same `true` an `'true'`. Try doing `console.log(true == 'true')`, it will give `false` because the first one is a bolean value (true or false) while the second one is an string value (`'any kind of text'`).

So to check the bolean correctly you should do:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox == true){
    console.log('The checkbox is true');
}
```

Or even you can do:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
console.log(checkbox);
if(checkbox){
    console.log('The checkbox is true');
}
```

Because `checkbox` is already a bolean and it will work with the `if()` statement. It's like doing `true == true` (that is `true`) and `false == true` (that is `false`), you are doing a redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the single quotes around true in your IF condition. It takes it as a string if you add quotes.

Try this:

if(checkbox == true){
...
}

This should work.